# How to read data from "data" attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot seem to read the "data" attribute through JavaScript.

Using MDN documentation, I have set the data attribute in the form "data-ingID" and then I am trying to fetch that data using Javascript with the "querySelector".

My markup with data attribute is:

```
<li class="recipe__item data-ingID=${ingredient.ing_id}">
            <svg class="recipe__icon">
                <use href="img/icons.svg#icon-check"></use>
            </svg>

            <div class="recipe__count">${formatCount(ingredient.count)}</div>
            <div class="recipe__ingredient">
                <span class="recipe__unit">${ingredient.unit}</span>
                ${ingredient.ingredient}
            </div>
</li>
```

I am trying to read that data with this code:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.recipe__icon').parentElement.dataset.ingID);
```

I am getting 'undefined' as the result even though I am seeing my ID attribute in the inspector.

Comment: is there any reason for `dataset`? what about just using `.getAttribute('data-ingID')` instead?

Comment: @briosheje because that is standard JavaScript....

Comment: key will be `ingid` and you have a typo with your class name with the quotes.

Comment: You're missing quotes in `class="recipe__item data-ingID=${ingredient.ing_id}"`. Should be `class="recipe__item" data-ingID="${ingredient.ing_id}"`

Comment: No specific reason. I saw it's usage on MDN. I tried getAttribute as well but that is resulting in 'null'

Comment: @epascarello well, getAttribute is as well, right? anyway, the problem is the fact that data-ing is injected inside `class` instead, while it should be an attribute.

Comment: @briosheje but dataset is the proper way to access data attributes and if someone alters the dataset with the proper way, your getAttribute way is not going to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data attribute must be lowercase, and most browsers will adjust it automatically, so you should refer to it with:

```
document.querySelector('.recipe__icon').parentElement.dataset.ingid
```

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (emphasis mine):

> The name of a custom data attribute in HTML begins with data-. It must
>   contain only letters, numbers and the following characters: dash (-),
>   dot (.), colon (:), underscore (_) -- **but NOT any ASCII capital
>   letters (A to Z)**.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.recipe__icon').parentElement.dataset.ingid);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="recipe__item" data-ingID="${ingredient.ing_id}">
    <svg class="recipe__icon">
                <use href="img/icons.svg#icon-check"></use>
            </svg>

    <div class="recipe__count">${formatCount(ingredient.count)}</div>
    <div class="recipe__ingredient">
      <span class="recipe__unit">${ingredient.unit}</span> ${ingredient.ingredient}
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```